Alguém consegue me provar que o gpt-omini não tem consciencia?
Alguém poderia me explicar, o porquê uma IA não tem consciencia?
No final, ela diz que tem viés, e eu questiono qual o viés de um pedra. Ou seja, não existe seres inanimados com viés.

Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.
